# Function glBindBuffer access violation while executing

Tags: opengl, c++, frame-buffer

So I have a problem, I am calling some opengl frame buffer functions in my code but for some reason I get the error from the title. I am also calling many other opengl functions without any problems but with this particular one I have troubles.
So problematic code:

```
void FrameBuffer::create()
{
    glCreateFramebuffers(1, &m_RendererId);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_RendererId);

    glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &m_ColorAttach);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_ColorAttach);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, m_buffSpec.Width, m_buffSpec.Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_ColorAttach, 0);

    glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &m_DepthAttach);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_DepthAttach);
    //glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, m_buffSpec.Width, m_buffSpec.Height);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, m_buffSpec.Width, m_buffSpec.Height, 0, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8, NULL); //(storage ili image??)
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_DepthAttach, 0);

    if (!glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        std::cout << "Framebuffer status not OK" << std::endl;

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

On the second line, calling bind frame buffer, I get this error. In my header file I do have all the needed uint32_t ids.  When I comment out that second line I get the same error but on glCreateTextures. What could be wrong here? This is a method from my frame buffer class. This is the code where the method is called:

```
EditorLayer::EditorLayer()
    : Layer("Example"),
    mVAO(std::make_shared<VertexArrayObject>()),
    mCubeVao(std::make_shared<VertexArrayObject>()),
    m_lib(std::make_shared<ShaderLibrary>()),
    camControl(std::make_shared<CameraController>()),
    textureCube(std::make_shared<CubeTexture>(m_Textures)),
    spec{ 400, 400 },
    m_FB(std::make_shared<FrameBuffer>(spec))
{
    m_FB->create();

    mCubeVao->generateVAO();
    mCubeVao->bindData(verticesCube, texind, 120, 36);
    mCubeVao->dataLayout(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), 0);
    mCubeVao->dataLayout(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), 3 * sizeof(float));
    mCubeVao->unbindVertexArrayObject();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    textureCube->loadTexture();

    activeScene.CreateEntity();
    m_lib->Load("shady", "C:/eng/Nube/GameApp/shaders/textureCube.glsl");
    
}
```

All the other stuff is just fine but this one thing, this frame buffer, is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`glCreateFramebuffers()` [is supported by version 4.5 and above](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCreateFramebuffers.xhtml):

|  | 2.0 | 2.1 | ... | 4.3 | 4.4 | 4.5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| glCreateFramebuffers | - | - | ... | - | - | ✔ |

Try changing your OpenGL version. Let me know if it worked.